# AddDays() not working within a while loop

Tags: c#

Is there anything that stops the `DateTime AddDays()` method that doesn't run within a while loop. I have this simple bit of code;

```
DateTime last_day = monthCalendar2.SelectionRange.End;
DateTime first_day = new DateTime(year, month, day);

//Insert dates into vector
while (first_day != last_day)
{
  dates.Add(first_day);
  first_day.AddDays(1);
}
```

I step through the program and first_day never changes, anyone know why?!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason being is that DateTime is [Immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), this means that you can't directly modify it and instead need to create a new instance of it. Strings are another type that behave in this way which you may be more used to.

```
first_day = first_day.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Thanks, but still a faster answer is almost always rated higher and accepted over a more descriptive answer.

Comment: That's why I first post a short answer and then make it more descriptive ;-) The higher rated answer is at the top and most people don't look any further.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Indeed - I was about 10 seconds shy of the first answer however by adding too much basic detail to mine... silly!

Comment: More like 24 seconds. And by that time his answer already got two or three upvotes and off it was :-)

Comment: Yes, because my answer had all data about the problem. It said `why` problem occurs (immutable struct) and `how` to fix it. Little searching on 'immutable' can explain what it means. Btw your answer does not provide other immutable examples and no code about how immutable could be implemented :)

Answer (score 11):

DateTime is immutable. You should do

```
first_day = first_day.AddDays(1);
```

UPDATE:
If you check [DateTime.AddDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) method description: `Returns a new System.DateTime that adds the specified number of days to the value of this instance.` That relates to all operations (such as Add, Substract, AddHours etc) on DateTime structure - any calculation does not modify the value of the structure. Instead, the calculation returns a new DateTime structure whose value is the result of the calculation. That's because DateTime is immutable struct. I.e. instance value cannot be changed after it was created.

Answer (score 4):

DateTime can't be changed, so instead do.

```
first_day = first_day.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for editing the code to look like code, I tend to forgot to do that right :/